# Adding word "Chapter" into Table of Contents for only numbered chapter entries

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I'm trying to use the `titletoc` package to add the word "Chapter" only to my numbered entries in my Table of Contents. I'm using a `report` document class. I'm really close (I think), I just need to know how to align the numberless entries with the word "Chapter" from the numbered entries.

Here's what I've got:

```
\usepackage{titletoc}% 
\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {}% <above-code>
  {\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {\bfseries}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>
```

Which gives me:

[image: Table of Contents result]

I'd like to align those numberless chapters on the left hand side with the word "Chapter". Also, I'm receiving `\hbox` warnings for the page numbers with four or more characters (such as viii) and am not sure what to do about those. I'm new to LaTeX and am at a loss. I tried looking through the `titletoc` documentation but was unsuccessful. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: As requested, here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titletoc}% 
\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {}% <above-code>
  {\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel:\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {\bfseries}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}      
\clearpage                  
\setcounter{page}{2}        

\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Abstract}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Acknowledgements}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{doublespace}
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Table of Contents}
\end{doublespace}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\setcounter{page}{255}  % % Uncomment to see \hbox warnings due to long TOC page number

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section one}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Another section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Note: remove the comment to receive the `\hbox` warnings. Thanks again

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Could you provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) so we have something to work with? Since this document seems like it will be very comprehensive (a thesis), be sure to give all details you require in terms of ToC-related packages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not using `\addcontentsline` in the correct way.

Instead of

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Abstract}
```

you have to use

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
```

and the result will be good.

Also notice that `\bfseries` can be specified in the first mandatory argument, so not to be repeated in the others:

```
\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {\bfseries}% <above-code>
  {\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel:\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titletoc}%
\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {\bfseries}% <above-code>
  {\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel:\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{2}

\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{doublespace}
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
\end{doublespace}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\setcounter{page}{255}  % % Uncomment to see \hbox warnings due to long TOC page number

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section one}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Another section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In regards of the Overfull `\hbox` warnings, I don't know a good way to solve it with `titletoc`, but I know a better way with `tocloft`, which works much better than `titletoc`.

So, you can replace the `titletoc` stuff

```
\usepackage{titletoc}%
\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {\bfseries}% <above-code>
  {\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel:\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>
```

with

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\newlength\mylength
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername~}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{:}
\settowidth\mylength{\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum\quad}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylength}
```

and the following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\newlength\mylength
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername~}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{:}
\settowidth\mylength{\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum\quad}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylength}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{2}

\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{doublespace}
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
\end{doublespace}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{255}  % % Uncomment to see \hbox warnings due to long TOC page number

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section one}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Another section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

will give you the following result

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me (based on your MWE), but it's a bit of a hack though.

```
\usepackage{titletoc}% 
\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {}% <above-code>
  {\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel:\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {\bfseries\raggedright\hspace{-0.575\linewidth}}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>
```

The hbox warnings look like they are caused by the page numbers being boldface for chapters (but not sections). Do you want it that way, or do you want all page numbers in the same (non-bold) font?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Nice answer, I cannot help but feel though that your last question would be better suited in a comment to the question.

Comment: Sure, but I don't have enough rep to do that. You can repost it there if you want.

Comment: Ahh, sorry I tend to forget these things.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that you are using `titletoc`, but I have recently had the same desire for a document that was already heavily dependent on `tocloft`.  For the sake of documenting the solution, I have achieved the same behavior with `tocloft` using the following:

```
\let\oldcftchappresnum\cftchappresnum
\renewcommand*{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter \oldcftchappresnum} %change the chapter number to include the word "Chapter"
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{6em} %Make space for the word "Chapter"... was previously set to 1.5em
```