# Add words to chapter numbering in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

In book class the table of contents appears as follows, with the first line having the chapter number.

[image: toc]

As you see, the chapter numbering appears horribly at the side of the chapter's name, since every chapter's name is a date and, thus, begins with a number as well.

Being these lessons, I'd like the chapter's number to appear this way instead: "**Lesson X. Date**". Example: "**Lesson 1. 04 Giugno 2018**".

I suppose it should be enough to renew the command that the table of contents uses to recall the number of the chapter, but I can't find which command it is.

Do you have a clue about how should I proceed?

**Edit 1**

The class I'm using is `book`.
The packages I'm using are `babel`, `inputenc`, `ulem`, `url`, `eurosym`, `fancyhdr`, `graphicx`, `wrapfig`, `geometry`.

I don't think a MWE is needed, but that would be:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, openany]{book}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{geometry}

\frenchspacing

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{4th June}
    \chapter{5th July}
\end{document}
```

Apparently the package `tocloft` could be the solution, but there must be some kind of conflict because here's what happenes if I use it as indicated in the related answer by Peter Wilson:

[image: tocloft]

As you see, it also modifies the space between lines.

Comment: This depends on your `\documentclass` and/or other packages you might be loading. [There](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171047/5764) [are](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/358989/5764) [options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/325565/5764). Can you provide the community with a complete, minimal example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, replicating your current setup?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `tocloft` package. For example (after eliminating any typos)

```
\documentclass[...]{...}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Lesson } % Put Lesson before chapter number
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.} % Put a period after the number
% add extra space for Lesson
\newlength{\tocl}% a scratch length
\settowidth{\tocl}{\bfseries\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}% extra space
\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\tocl}% add the extra space 
...
\begin{document}
...
\tableofcontents
...
\chapter{04 Giugno 2018}
...
\end{document}
```

Read the manual (`> texdoc tocloft`) for more information. I should have done that before posting as I initially forgot to allow for the extra space required for `Lesson`.

Comment: This works great but the words I add this way don't "move" the chapter's name in the toc; as a consequence all the pieces before and after the chapter's name, and the chapter's name itself, overlap themselves. I checked and the package's documentation doesn't specify conflicts with other packages I'm using, nor it mentions this occurrance. I'll put a screenshot in the opening post. Might this be a bug? I see that this package is quite recent

Comment: @ilmietitore My apologies, in my initial posting I forgot to allow for the extra space required for `Lesson`. I originally developed `tocloft` in 1998. It was a posting bug, not a package bug.

Comment: Now it works. Still, the lineskip becomes shorter, as shown in the screenshots above. Is there a way to leave it as it as by default? The package documentation doesn't mention this occurrance.