# How can I prefix the term "Chapter" to the chapter number in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a table of contents as follows:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\chapter{TEST}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Test section one}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\end{document}
```

I want to appear statement "Chapter 1: TEST" instead of "1 TEST" in the list of contents. Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution that employs the `tocloft` package:

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter }
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{:}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\bfseries Chapter 1:\ } % if more than 9 chapters, use "Chapter 10"
\cftsetindents{chap}{0pt}{\mylen}
```

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter }
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{:}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\bfseries Chapter 1:\ }
\cftsetindents{chap}{0pt}{\mylen}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{TEST}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Test section one}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the way:

```
\documentclass{report}
%%%%%ADDED CODE%%%%%
\usepackage{titletoc}% 
\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {\bfseries}% <above-code>
  {\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel:\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>
%%%%%%END OF ADDED CODE%%%%%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\chapter{TEST}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Test section one}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\end{document}
```

Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171061/120578

Output:

[image]