# Default arguments for tabletoc tablecontents?

Tags: titletoc

I am trying to add some text in my table of contents a la [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171047/adding-word-chapter-into-table-of-contents-for-only-numbered-chapter-entries).  I am already using `titlesec`, so the `titlecontents` command from the `titletoc` package seems to fit the bill.  However, I am not sure how to only edit the bits that I need.  Specifically, the example in the linked question:

```
\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {}% <above-code>
  {\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel:\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {\bfseries}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>
```

Changes a great deal about the formatting.  It seems that many of these arguments are mandatory, and I'm not sure how to obtain the defaults.  Specifically, I would like to only change the second mandatory argument (to get the `\chaptername` in the entry), but would not like to change any of the other behavior (the last argument, for example, gets rid of the line of dots).

What are the defaults for the `\titlecontents{chapter}`?

Comment: Usually, there's no line of dots for chapters – only for sections. Which document class do you use?

Comment: I am using a variant of the puthesis class from [here](https://www.purdue.edu/gradschool/research/thesis/templates.html)

Comment: If I do not include the above hunk of code, then I get dots for chapters as well.  That is the desired behavior.

Comment: It is due to this line in the cls file: `\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}`

Comment: These commands come from `tocloft` . You shouldn't use packages which tackle the same things. It's preferable to use the tools from tocloft. See p.11 of the documenntation of the latter package on how to add something in the number box